# Rewriting google chart script in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-api

I'm having trouble getting a google chart to display using React. I'm really new to React and struggling but here is the script file I have so far. The script is being called from the head of a separate html page and in the body of that page I have a div with the id "line". I just get a blank page when it is loaded.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

var Chart = React.createClass({
    displayName: "Chart",
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: this.getData()
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        document.getElementById('line');
        )
        },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.draw();
        setInterval(this.update, 4000);
    },
    update: function(){
        this.setState({
            data : this.getData()
        });
        this.draw();
    },
    draw: function() {
        var data = this.state.data;
        var options = {
            title: 'Chart showing random data auto updating',
            vAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                    max: 40,
                    min: 0
                }
            }
        };
        var element = document.getElementById(this.props.graphName);
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(element);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    },
    getData: function() {
        return google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Random X', 'Random Y'],
            ['1', Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1],
            ['2', Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1],
            ['3', Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1],
            ['4', Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1],
            ['5', Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1],
        ]);
    }
});
function init() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Chart graphName="line"/>,
        document.getElementById('body')
    );
}
```

Comment: So is the init method being called?

Comment: isn't it called with the google.setonloadcallback?

Comment: I have never used google charts, whatever that is. Just place a console.log in `init()` and see what happens. For all I know you don't even have to put the render function inside of setonloadcallback.

Comment: I don't think it's logging anything right now when I place it inside init()

Comment: What if you move the render function outside of the init function?

Comment: it's still not working for me, I might just leave it out of a react format if possible

Comment: If you do decide to keep using React, I would get that working before I implement the google charts thingy. For starters you should return a valid React element in the `render()` method. And don't append react elements to document.body in ReactDOM.render

Comment: okay thanks I changed some of the mistakes on that part but still having issues but thanks for the insight